# Caliburn Micro Conventions: How to Remove "DesignTime" from ViewModel name and namespaces

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, design-time

I use Caliburn.Micro and want to add an additional type mapping for design time visualization of views.

I have the following structure:
SomeNameSpace.SomeViewModel
SomeNamespace.SomeView

and for design time support (same assembly)
SomeNamespace.DesignTime.DesignSomeViewModel (or DesignTimeSomeViewModel)

I want to achieve that Caliburn.Micro resolves (at design time) for DesignSomeViewModel to SomeViewModel and strips of .DesignTime from the namespace.

However... I didn't succeed yet.

I tried the following in the bootstrapper:

```
protected override void Configure()
{
  // ...

   ViewLocator.AddDefaultTypeMapping("Design");

   // not good, want something generic (but even this did not work)
   ViewLocator.AddNamespaceMapping("*.DesignTime", "Some.Library");
   ViewLocator.NameTransformer.AddRule("Design", string.Empty);
   ViewLocator.NameTransformer.AddRule(".DesignTime", string.Empty);
```

So that I can reference the designTime viewmodels:

```
cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=designTime:DesignSomeViewModel,
```

IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}

... and create DesignTimeViewModels like this:

```
public class DesignContainerViewModel : Screen, IContainerViewModel
{
    public DesignContainerViewModel()
    {
        this.Text = "DesignTime Container";
        this.Child = new DesignChildViewModel();
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public IScreen Child { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what is the ultimate goal you are looking for?

Comment: @mvermef I want to have DesignTimeViewModels resolved to their corresponding ViewModels from the real ViewModel resolved at runtime, For example MyViewModel -> DesignTimeMyViewModel -> MyView instead of DesignTimeViewModel -> DesignTimeView

Comment: @mvermef Not sure I am on the right track, but the DesignTime support of CM is somewhat weird to me. This should be more clear here (also with programming example from me) https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/359

Comment: ... in the end... just want to have separate ViewModels and DesignTimeViewmodel that are used by the same View (DesignTime <vs> Runtime). I want to see what I am doing with the designer of VS. Should be possible but I don't know exactly how the resolution is done at DesignTime (View knows DesignViewModel at DesignTime => DataContext and so on, resolving with CM seems different between designtime and runtime -> look at StartDesignTime and StartRuntime methods)

Comment: There is also another issue close to this topic here https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/358

Comment: keep in mind that d: is ignore at runtime anyway and separation of designtime vs runtime is moot other than folder separation.

Comment: Yes, I know that d is ignored. That is the behavior I want. Simple models for design with less dependencies and complex models for runtime with same interface. Designtime aspects should not reflect in the runtime models. For example think about constructor arguments for runtime models that point to some other models etc. Don't want to add constructor without parameters and curious defaults just because designtime needs this.

Comment: The only otherway to maybe achieve this is a bootstrapper swap but even then it might be more work than you want to deal with. DesignTimeBootstrapper vs RunTimeBootstrapper  I don't believe that with ViewLocator will this work without source changes, with present setup.